# How to bookmark in file explorer Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, gnome-shell-extension, extension

- Where is my **bookmark** in the file explorer of Ubuntu 20.04 !!!????

I cannot find it ...I have just updated my system from Ubuntu 18.04, and I love the Bookmark system in Ubuntu 18.04 very much. It was simple, easy, and gives that clear visibility.  But right now I have to move to Ubuntu 20.04 for other software usages, and really cannot go back to Ubuntu 18.04.

- And if **Starred** is the replacement of Bookmark... Could someone please tell me how to expand the Starred folder on the left panel....?

I really want something that allows me to see the folder inside there...

[image]   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just drag whatever you want to the left.   When dragging you will probably see `New Bookmark` appear.  Just drag whatever it is that you want over that `New Bookmark` to add it.

Example:

*Dragging `Calibre Library` folder to the left showing Add Bookmark:*

[image]

*Bookmark added for `Calibre Library`:*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

- Using the keyboard shortcut from the folder you want to bookmark: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.
- Using "drag & drop" as @Terrance explains it. Note: "Add new bookmark" only appears if you drag the folder that you want to bookmark.

The second option is quite hidden and thus somewhat unfortunate...rather a bug than a design feature.

Comment: it wants to work with documents/files too, as dragging and dropping brings up the 'new bookmark' but then nothing happens. Ubu 20.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a third option for those who want to script the bookmarks to share them on different computers

```
nano ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

And then type whatever you need

```
file:///home/<useraccount>/Videos
file:///home/<useraccount>/Downloads
file:///home/<useraccount>/Dropbox
```